# Return result of nested promise success function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, promise, nested

I am building a wrapper function to retrieve values stored in a WebExtension's local Storage. I am struggeling to pass the return value of the success function to its outer function. Many thanks in advance!

```
 get(key) {

    browser.storage.local.get(key).then(onGot, onError);

    function onGot(storage) {

        console.log(storage[key]); // Works so far
    }

    function onError() {

        return false;
    }

    // How can I return storage[key] here?
}
```

Comment: Just add `return` to `return  browser.storage.local.get...` then do `get().then(...`

Answer (score 0):

Either return a promise from the wrapper or let your promise resolve and consume the result with a callback.

A promise represents an operation which may or may not have completed yet. It provides hooks for success and failure so that the result of the **async** operation can be processed.

In order to return from the function, the caller and the executing function should stay in **sync** (w.r.t control flow). This moves away from **async**, which is what js promise is for.